# how can i make 4 rows into 1 row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python3 and jupyter notebook in intel-cpu mac

I want to make 15 column and 25600 rows csv file
into

60 column and 6400 rows

just making

new 0th row = 0th row, 1st row, 2nd row, 3rd row

new 1th row = 4th row, 5th row, 6th row, 7th row

and so on

what can i do?

Comment: what do you mean `new 0th row = 0th row, 1st row, 2nd row, 3rd row`....  the sum, an average, a concatenation ?   not clear what the question requires.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df2 = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[i:i+4].stack().tolist()).T for i in range(0, len(df), 4)]
).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = np.ravel([df.columns]*4)
```

Basically get 4 rows stack them and form a list and concatenate them into a dataframe.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(25600,15)))
df.columns = df.columns.map('a{}'.format)
```

print(df):

```
       a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10  a11  a12  a13  a14
0       5   6   4   7   8   5   1   4   2   3    3    5    9    5    9
1       9   5   6   8   8   7   3   1   3   8    9    6    3    8    1
2       5   8   4   9   8   8   3   6   5   3    4    7    3    3    6
3       6   2   5   9   5   8   6   4   1   5    6    4    2    8    7
4       2   6   4   9   4   1   1   6   5   5    6    2    3    8    8
...    ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
25595   6   1   1   6   3   7   8   4   7   3    6    5    3    4    6
25596   5   5   1   8   3   1   6   3   1   4    1    6    8    7    7
25597   6   7   2   3   9   4   6   8   5   5    3    4    4    8    2
25598   6   7   2   9   8   9   6   5   9   2    2    2    8    9    7
25599   1   4   2   4   3   7   8   4   6   7    3    4    3    2    7


df2 = pd.concat(
        [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[i:i+4].stack().tolist()).T for i in range(0, len(df), 4)]
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.columns = np.ravel([df.columns]*4)
```

print(df2)

```
      a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  ...  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10  \
0      5   6   4   7   8   5   1   4   2   3  ...   8   6   4   1   5    6   
1      2   6   4   9   4   1   1   6   5   5  ...   9   8   8   6   3    3   
2      7   2   6   9   6   8   3   3   7   3  ...   4   7   8   9   5    8   
3      8   7   1   7   1   9   3   3   4   6  ...   6   2   2   6   6    8   
4      4   7   9   6   3   1   1   6   3   9  ...   3   6   2   6   6    2   
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...   
6395   4   6   2   8   8   2   1   5   7   6  ...   7   5   3   4   2    5   
6396   2   2   7   4   3   8   6   6   2   2  ...   8   2   3   6   8    8   
6397   6   4   5   3   6   9   8   8   7   6  ...   9   7   7   4   5    4   
6398   6   3   7   5   4   3   2   5   5   1  ...   7   8   4   7   3    6   
6399   5   5   1   8   3   1   6   3   1   4  ...   7   8   4   6   7    3   

      a11  a12  a13  a14  
0       4    2    8    7  
1       4    4    9    8  
2       3    1    7    7  
3       6    6    4    9  
4       3    4    2    2  
...   ...  ...  ...  ...  
6395    4    8    9    4  
6396    8    5    8    5  
6397    9    3    9    6  
6398    5    3    4    6  
6399    4    3    2    7
```

Comment: sorry I am late! thank you very much for your help!